# Example of homeomorphism of $S^1$ which behaves badly relatively to the Lebesgue measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Could anyone give an example of a homeomorphism of $S^1$ which sends an open set of full Lebesgue measure on an open set which has not full measure ?

Comment: Maybe try some sort of modified Cantor function.

Answer (score 0):

Such maps abound and, moreover, they appear very naturally. Recall that a map of two measure spaces is said to have *Luzin's Property N* if it sends each set of zero measure to a set of zero measure. In your setting (of homeomorphisms $f: S^1\to S^1$) Luzin's Property N is equivalent to absolute continuity of $f^{-1}$. Examples of homeomorphisms $S^1\to S^1$ which are not absolutely continuous appear naturally in the *Teichmuller Theory*: Suppose that $S_1, S_2$ are two compact hyperbolic surfaces of the same genus, $S_i=H^2/\Gamma_i$, where $\Gamma_i< PSL(2,R)$ is a Fuchsian subgroup. Then there exists a quasi-symmetric homeomorphisms $f: S^1\to S^1$ equivariant with respect to the isomorphism $\Gamma_1\to \Gamma_2$ (induced by a homeomorphism $S_1\to S_2$).

**Theorem.** $f$ is an element of $PLS(2,R)$ if and only if it is absolutely continuous.

See this paper by Agard: ["Remarks on the boundary mapping for a Fuchsian group"](http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol10/vol10pp001-013.pdf). In fact, Agard proves much more: If $f$ has nonzero derivative at one point, then $f\in PSL(2,R)$.